# iTunes Match questions regarding songs marked as "Uploaded"

Tags: itunes, itunes-match

I have about 800 songs marked as "Uploaded".  I would love for them to be replaced by "Matched" 256kbps AAC files.

Will iTunes Match ever re-check songs that have been flagged as Uploaded at some later point. Is there a way to re-submit them for checking?

Comment: Is there something about those songs that's different from the others? Maybe CD rips at a very low bit rate? Curious why so many don't match.

Answer (score 1):

I have over 5000 tracks which have been uploaded, whenever I add new music, Match is updated, and it determines whether to upload it or match it.

I was interested in this also, so I created a smart playlist for the kind set to MPEG audio and within the playlist I display the iTunes Match columns.

Recently I checked this list, and instead of all of them displaying Uploaded, a couple of hundred had changed to Matched, so I deleted them locally and re-downloaded the matched version.

So in answer to your question, yes, they are sometimes updated, and there's nothing you need to do other than occasionally update match by adding new music, or manually from the menu, and then check your smart playlist.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you can go to the Store menu in iTunes and click "Update iTunes Match" and iTunes will rescan your library for any changes, as well as scan the Uploaded items to see if they can be matched. I am not 100% sure on this, but that's how it seems to work on my machine.

Comment: I was wondering if that went through the Uploaded list as well.  I never see the Uploaded count change, so I wasn't sure.  Thanks

Comment: Uploaded probably won't change that often, because when music is released, labels/artists upload it to all the pertinent sites; iTunes, Amazon, Napster, Rhapsody, etc. How often do you think back-catalogs are uploaded? Outside of high-profile events (see: Beatles), probably not nearly as often. It's pretty hard to track the timeline of something like that too.